# List PIDs of processes that require high perf GPU

Tags: macos, terminal

Macbook Pro with Radeon card is huge pain. Is there a way to list in terminal processes/PIDs that use high perf GPU so I could easily kill them? I know Activity Monitor has "Energy" tab and there you can see processes that require high perf GPU but doing this every time I restart/login to mac is tedious. Right now I have one app that everytime it is run requires killing one thread that requires high perf GPU. gfxcardstatus gives me pids but then there is no interface to kill the process so I need to manually rewrite PID to terminal in order to kill the process.